# Applying Conditional Exclusions to Pandas DataFrame using Counts

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
example_data = [{'ticker': 'aapl', 'loc': 'us'}, {'ticker': 'mstf', 'loc': 'us'}, {'ticker': 'baba', 'loc': 'china'}, {'ticker': 'ibm', 'loc': 'us'}, {'ticker': 'db', 'loc': 'germany'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)
print df

loc ticker
0       us   aapl
1       us   mstf
2    china   baba
3       us    ibm
4  germany     db
```

I want to create a new DataFrame such that each row is created from the original df but rows with loc counts greater than 2 are excluded.  That is, the new df is created by looping through the old df, counting the number of loc rows that have come before, and including / excluding the row based on this count.

The following code gives the desired output.

```
country_counts = {}
output = []
for row in df.values:
    if row[0] not in country_counts:
        country_counts[row[0]] = 1
    else:
        country_counts[row[0]] +=1
    if country_counts[row[0]] <= 2:
        output.append({'loc': row[0], 'ticker': row[1]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame(output)   
print new_df

loc ticker
0       us   aapl
1       us   mstf
2    china   baba
3  germany     db
```

The output excludes the 4th row in the original df because its loc count is greater than 2 (i.e. 3).

Does there exist a better method to perform this type of operation?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about groupby and `.head`:

```
In [90]: df.groupby('loc').head(2)
Out[90]: 
       loc ticker
0       us   aapl
1       us   mstf
2    china   baba
4  germany     db
```

Also, be careful with your column names, since `loc` clashes with the `.loc` method.